# Issue with iframe in Dash bootstrap components tab

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a callback that creates a url for a weather radar image. This includes a timestamp which is rounded to the nearest 5 mins relative to the current time. An example is shown below.

'https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/weather/maps-and-charts/rainfall-radar-forecast-map#?bbox=[[50.546,-2.200],[52.140,2.944]]&model=ukmo-ukv&layer=rainfall-rate&timestep=1680109809000'

If I paste this directly into a browser all is well. However, when provided into an Iframe, I get an error message. Its not that the url cannot be found, its just that it doesn't like the timestep as shown.

[image]

The code for the Iframe is below:

```
       dbc.Tab([
        dbc.Row([
            dbc.Col([
                html.H1(children='Data is usually updated every 2 hours', style=style_2),
            ], width=2, style={'height': '100vh'}),
            dbc.Col([

                html.Br(), html.H1(children='Weather Forecast.', style=style_1),
                html.H1(children='Current radar', style=style_2),
                html.Iframe(id='radar',src=rain_radar, style={"height": "600px", "width": "100%"}),
                dcc.Graph(id='forecast_rain_prob', figure=fig_forecast_rain_prob, config=config),
                html.Br(),
                dcc.Graph(id='forecast_daily_rain_prob', figure=fig_daily_rain_prob, config=config),
                html.Br(),
                dcc.Graph(id='forecast_temperature', figure=fig_tempreture, config=config),
                html.Br(),
                dcc.Graph(id='forecast_cloud', figure=fig_cloud, config=config),
                html.Br(),
                html.Br(),
                dcc.Graph(id='wind_speed', figure=fig_wind, config=config),
                dcc.Graph(id='wind_direction', figure=fig_wind_direction, config=config),
                dcc.Interval(id="forecast_trigger", interval=1000 * 60 * 60 * 2),  # milliseconds

            ])
        ])
    ], label="Weather forecast",tab_id='tab-7'),  # end tab
```

The really strange thing is that sometimes it DOES work. Any advice would be much appreciated!

EDIT:
Great point Eric re the callback. Its this

```
@app.callback([Output('forecast_rain_prob', 'figure'), #forecast tab
            Output('forecast_temperature', 'figure'),
            Output('wind_speed', 'figure'),
            Output('wind_direction', 'figure'),
            Output('radar', 'src'),
            Output('forecast_cloud','figure'),
            Output('forecast_daily_rain_prob','figure')
           ],
          Input('forecast_trigger', 'n_intervals'))
def update_forecast(n):
    fig_forecast_rain_prob,fig_tempreture,fig_wind,fig_wind_direction,fig_river_forcast,  fig_cloud, rain_radar, fig_daily_rain, df_daily_forecast = forecast.get_open_meteo_forecast()
    update_time = datetime.now()

return fig_forecast_rain_prob,fig_tempreture,fig_wind,fig_wind_direction, rain_radar, fig_cloud,fig_daily_rain
```

Comment: The error may comes from the callback that sets the url, could you add the relevant code ?

Comment: thanks EricLavault 2 have added above